# Regex in JavaScript, Can I replace only an inner specific group instead of full string?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
regex: Morning, ((.*?) (.*?) (.*?) group)
input: Morning, I am inner group
```

Please see the above code. In this case I would like to replace "inner" to "nested", but I cannot find a way to do this. All the replacement methods I have seen are either for flat grouping (not nested) or replacing the whole line.

May I know if there a way to achieve what I want? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lookbehind and lookahead assertions could handle this. See [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Also, note that `.*` will include spaces.

Comment: `inner` is matched with Group 3, so replace with `$2 nested $4 group`. Why do you use so many groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to specify the `d` flag as for [`hasIndices`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/hasIndices) so you can get the indices of a specific group.

Once you get the start and end indices of that group, you can just concatenate the first part and second part with the replacement easily:

```js
const regex = /Morning, ((.*?) (.*?) (.*?) group)/d;
const input = "Morning, I am inner group";

// in this case, you want to get the indices of the 4th group
const [start, end] = input.match(regex).indices[4];
const output = input.slice(0, start) + 'nested' + input.slice(end);

console.log(output);
```